# Restart an node.js app from itself while keeping stdin and readline available

Tags: node.js

I want to be able to use readline, quit the current process and restart it, keeping stdin as well as readline capabilites.

Example code follows:

```
var readline = require('readline');
var fork = require('child_process').fork;

console.log("argv:", process.argv);

var rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

rl.on('line', (input) => {
  console.log(`>>>: ${input}`);

  if (input==="exit"){
    process.exit();
    return;
  }

  if (input==="restart"){
    rl.close(); // whatever, has no effect
    restartApp();
    return;
  }
});

function restartApp() {
  process.on('exit', (code) => {
    console.log(`About to exit with code: ${code}`);

    var forked = fork(process.argv[1], ["RESTARTED"]);
  });

  process.exit();
}
```

When this script runs it will wait until the user types an "exit" or "restart" string.

All is nice until it restarts and one keystroke is sent on stdin, throwing the following error:

```
events.js:161
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: read EIO
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1028:11)
    at TTY.onread (net.js:572:26)
```

How do I want to prevent this error?

I was reading child_process documentation as well as readline, but something is missing.

It seems that keystrokes are being sent to the old process.

Yes, I know nodemon, forever and pm2 modules. They can "solve" this problem, but I want to learn what I'm missing.

Comment: Not sure this is possible, as you'd need something like `execve` to implement this, and I'm not sure if that's even exposed in any way (certainly not through `child_process.fork`, perhaps through `child_process.spawn` but some quick tests make me think that's not going to work either).

Comment: I think this is the wrong approach. Cluster with (with one master and one slave) is more fit for this task.

Comment: You mean the master would keep reading from stdin and pass the data to a child process that may be restarted?

Comment: No, child listens from stdin (or repl) and sends master a message requesting a process restart (kill and fork again).

Comment: Oh right. Yeah, that would work :) Although you wouldn't even need to send the master a message: if you listen for the [`exit`](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_event_exit_1) event in the master, then whenever the child exits (using `process.exit()`) the master will get notified. You can use an exit code to signal if it needs to be restarted or not.

Comment: Good point @robertklep!